# On macOS Monterey, cannot create shortcut actions with Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst, sirishortcuts, macos-monterey

We are trying to create shortcut actions with Catalyst.

Our app is already available on Mac, and we previously integrated the intents framework on iOS. So according to the WWDC21 "Meet Shortcuts on macOS" [presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10232?time=1383), "it's likely that [we] have compiled out [our] Intents integration in the process of coming to Mac". So, it's no surprise that we cannot create shortcut actions for Mac in our app with Catalyst.

The WWDC presentation suggests to "make sure to audit your code to re-enable this functionality when running on macOS Monterey." We do not understand what we need to do based on this suggestion.

What we tried so far :

- we managed to create shortcut actions for mac with Catalyst, in the app available at https://github.com/mralexhay/ShortcutsExample. So, the problem does come from our app.
- we managed to create shortcut actions for **iOS** in our app
- we tried to create a fresh intent extension in our app, but the shortcut actions are still available only on iOS, not on Mac.

Has anyone found a solution in a similar situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a shortcut action, Shortcuts get mixed up with app identifiers. You therefore need to delete **all** the compiled versions of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem with this example "Meet Shortcuts on macOS", I haven't done anything with shortcuts before, but I have with AppleScripts. I have managed to sort out a couple of problem due to beta changes, but I end up with this method

```
let task = createTask(name: title, due: dueDate)
```

Which doesn't exist, worst still its suppose to return a Task to set to the CreateTaskIntentResponse.task property, but Task is already defined. So I can't really redefine it and besides it seems like it should be a generated type based on all the intent info I supplied.